# Insert Iframe Into a Div Using Javascript - for Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, dom, greasemonkey

I need to insert an iframe into a div using javascript.  I need this written in javascript so I can use the code in a greasemonkey script (and greasemonkey only allows for javascript).

The greasemonkey script will be inserting AOL's search bar into various websites.  I've included the working HTML code below so you can test it out to see what the end result is when this works.

Here is exactly what I need to do, written in HTML:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 564px; height: 43px; position: relative;">
<iframe src="http://aol.com" style="border: 0pt none ; left: -453px; top: -70px; position: absolute; width: 1440px; height: 775px;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

I need to make that HTML code work in greasemonkey, which requires it being written in javascript.  Here is what I've got so far (with my final question beneath the "pseudo-code"):

```
var makeIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
makeIframe.setAttribute("src", "http://aol.com");
makeIframe.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
makeIframe.setAttribute("border", "0pt");
makeIframe.setAttribute("border", "none");
makeIframe.setAttribute("left", "-453px");
makeIframe.setAttribute("top", "-70px");
makeIframe.setAttribute("position", "absolute");
makeIframe.setAttribute("width", "1440px");
makeIframe.setAttribute("height", "775px");
makeIframe.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");

var makediv = document.createElement("div");
makediv.setAttribute("height", "43px");
makediv.setAttribute("width", "564px");
makediv.setAttribute("position", "relative");
makediv.setAttribute("overflow", "hidden");
```

I already know how to either insert the iframe OR insert the div into the source code of the sites I need to insert it into, by doing this:

```
var getRef = document.getElementById("div-id-to-insert-element-before");
var parentDiv = getRef.parentNode;
parentDiv.insertBefore(iframe OR div, getRef);
```

What I CAN'T figure out how to do, is how to write the iframe INTO the div and then insert that div into the source code.  That very last code snippet works for inserting either the div or the iframe into the source code, but I need the iframe inside the div, and then for that div to be inserted into the source code (using that last code snippet).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1- you can use [element.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild)

```
makediv.appendChild(makeIframe);
```

2- Or append iframe as html into div like this,

```
makediv.innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://aol.com" style="border: 0pt none ;'+ 
                    'left: -453px; top: -70px; position: absolute;'+ 
                    'width: 1440px;'+ 
                    'height: 775px;" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
```

than insert makediv to where you want,

```
var getRef = document.getElementById("div-id-to-insert-element-before");
var parentDiv = getRef.parentNode;
parentDiv.insertBefore(makediv, getRef);
```

**UPDATE:**

You cannot set style with `setAttribute` function,

```
var makeIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
makeIframe.setAttribute("src", "http://aol.com");
makeIframe.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
makeIframe.style.border = "none";
makeIframe.style.left =  "-453px";
makeIframe.style.top = "-70px";
makeIframe.style.position = "absolute";
makeIframe.style.width = "1440px";
makeIframe.style.height = "775px";

var makediv = document.createElement("div");
makediv.style.height = "43px";
makediv.style.width = "564px";
makediv.style.position = "relative";
makediv.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

Comment: While both of those suggestions actually work for getting the iframe into the div, for some reason, the iframe shows up full size (it "explodes" out of the div).

Comment: In other words, the div doesn't contain the iframe & hide the overflow as it should.  While the HTML code works exactly as it should, this shows the entire full page iframe.  The top left of the iframed page shows up aligned with the top left of where the div is inserted into the page, which tells me the iframe is inside the div.  The div just doesn't stop the iframe from showing full size the way it does when you load that same code written in plain HTML.  Maybe it's a greasemonkey flaw?  Or is there something wrong with the JS code?

Comment: @Robert, I couldn't see at the first time, but you have one more error in your code, you cannot set style of element with `setAttribute` function, look my updated answer again.

Comment: That's fantastic ocanal, it works!  Thank you so much, not only for taking the time to answer, but then for coming back after I left a comment & reviewing & rewriting your answer.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Using on page reload the page redirected to the src URL of the *iframe*.
To avoid this use sandbox *iframe*, like this:

```
<pre>
<code>
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts" src="https://yoururl.com/"></iframe>
</code>
</pre>
```