# Javascript: Create element that does not inherit css?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple greasemonkey script for school that adds an ugly yellow box with some links to all websites. Currently I simply do this:

```
var guesses_div = document.createElement("div");
guesses_div.style.position = "fixed";
guesses_div.style.right = "0";
guesses_div.style.bottom = "0";
guesses_div.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 0)"
// here I add some links to the "guesses_div"
```

This code works fine. However, it inherits the style from the web page it's on. Is there a way to prevent this? Other than overriding all the style elements one by one?

Thanks!

Comment: If your css is written to encompass all elements, then either re-write the css to be less inclusive, or override all the styles. That's it

Comment: The point is that I didn't write the css. It's added to all websites, not just my own. So I can't alter the css.

Comment: Looks like its option #2 then I'm afraid: manually unpicking / restyling the inherited stuff.   I dont know much about `iframes`, but I know they dont pick up the parent css, so maybe that's an option.  Like I say, I don't know much though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No. There is no way to prevent the inherited css.

Long answer: Yes. You should manually override the inherited css rules.

Comment: `all: unset` is extremely bad for performance, better not to use

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the nicest way ever to do things, but in html5 you can use close to everything as tag name - so to not let your div inherit the sites css rules for a div, simply don't create a `div`, but `myDiv` for example

```
var guesses_div = document.createElement("myDiv");
guesses_div.style.position = "fixed";
guesses_div.style.right = "0";
guesses_div.style.bottom = "0";
guesses_div.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 0)"
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zyzfkwc5/)

Answer (score 0):

How about inserting an `iframe` instead of `div`? `iframe` will not inherit style from its parent.

If in doubt how to do that please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598345/insert-iframe-into-a-div-using-javascript-for-greasemonkey) question.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) property, and do something like:

```
var guesses_div = document.createElement("div");
guesses_div.style.all = "unset";
guesses_div.style.position = "fixed";
guesses_div.style.right = "0";
guesses_div.style.bottom = "0";
guesses_div.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
```

Unfortunately this does not work in IE or Safari yet, but as you're using Greasemonkey (only available for Firefox, I believe), you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible by creating [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components) which render their content in the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM), or simply attaching a shadow DOM to any element on the page and programmatically adding html/elements to it via JavaScript.

We can also do it declaratively without any JavaScript as follows:

```css
span {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <span>I'm a span in the shadow DOM</span>
  </template>
</div>

<span>I'm a span outside the shadow DOM</span>
```